# Why is the equilibrium macrostate of a system the most probable macrostate for an extremely large number of particles?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

My text book is trying to explain the cause of the 2nd law of thermodynamics through statistical mechanics using the distribution of N particles free to move between 2 connected containers. The ratio of microstates of a given macrostate to those of the most probable macrostate is plotted like this.

[image]

> For large values of N there extremely large numbers of microstates, but nearly all the microstates belong to the configuration in which molecules are divided equally

What I don't understand is how it concludes that most of the microstates correspond to the most probable macrostate as N increases from the graph of relative microstates. When I actually plot the ratio of microstates to the total microstates, the maximum of the curve decreases and goes to 0.

Doesn't this mean that the probability of the most probable macrostate (the one with greatest entropy) is almost 0 for a large number of particles? This clearly contradicts the 2nd law. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What relation did you get for the ratio of microstates to the total microstates as a function of $n$?

Comment: Think about this:  what is the integral of Dirac delta function $\delta\left(n-\frac{N}{2}\right)$ from $n=\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^-$ to $n=\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^+$?

Comment: I used nCr(N,n)/2^n

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH, the total number of states is $2^N$; each of the $N$ particles can independently be in either the left or right side. $n$ is the number of particles in the left (or right) side. The function nCr(N,n)/2^N has a maximum at $n = N/2$ as we would expect.

Comment: The problem is that the maximum also goes to 0 as N increases. So nearly all the microstates DONT correspond to the most probable macrostate. Infact, none of them should as N becomes very large

Comment: You have to consider *densities*. Of course, a microstates with $N/2$ particles in each half has essentially the same probability as a microstate with $N/2+1$ in one half and $N/2-1$ in the other half (when $N$ is large). What is relevant is that, as $N\to\infty$, the fraction of microstates with asymptotic density $1/2$ tends to $1$. (In fact, typical fluctuations of the number of particles in each half is of order $\sqrt{N}$, so fluctuations in the density is of order $1/\sqrt{N}$.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik I think I understand your point, But what do you precisely mean by 'densities', and how do I conclude graphically that the fraction of microstates which essentially correspond to N/2 in the limit is 1?

Comment: This is explained with all details in Section 1.3.1 of [our book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). I am a bit too lazy to reproduce the argument here (the book is freely downloadable).